# Does Stripe's API pull the URL of the webpage where the transaction takes place?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

**Scenario #1:** You have 5 separate Stripe accounts but 1 website, so you somehow rotate those 5 payment gateways on that 1 website. Now if 10 sales come in, then if equally distributed, each Stripe account gets 2 sales. Will Stripe see that the transactions actually originated from the same URL?

**Scenario #2:** You have 5 separate websites but 1 Stripe account. Now if each website generates 2 sales there will be 10 sales on that 1 Stripe account. Will Stripe see that the transactions actually originated from different URLs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a website or an active HTTP request on a web server to use the Stripe API. The Stripe API has no idea about the context in which you're making a call to their database. No, they do not know the URL of the website associated with your web server. All they know is the IP address of your server making the API call.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. While it's true for the server-side requests, it's not true for the client-side request to collect card details securely. Also Stripe explicitly requests to have separate Stripe accounts if you have separate websites/businesses: https://stripe.com/docs/multiple-accounts

Comment: If you use [tag:stripe.js], sure, that's a different topic. And yes, whatever OP is trying to do there seems fishy; but I'm not going to go into that at all.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! So basically with REST api Stripe will only get the host IP while with JS api they will get the domain info as well? Any way to circumvent that?

Comment: @Aleksandr Any specific reason why you need to circumvent that…‽

Comment: Looking to rotate processors in order to mitigate risk and dilute CB% but I suppose makes more sense then to just go with REST rather than JS. Still curious about JS though.